# put integer in queue<char> C++

Tags: c++, stl, queue, type-conversion

Hi I want to put each byte of an integer in a queue but for some reason I get a different value out.

```
int integer = 100;
char *chrp = (char *) &integer;
char charBuffer[10];
std::queue<char> queue;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
    queue.push(chrp[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
    charBuffer[i] = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
}

int *result = (int *) charBuffer;
```

I don't see why `*result` is not equal with integer. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? It is the same on my machine somehow.

Comment: Not an issue in this exact sample code, but if the queue would contain more than one integer, you may overwrite memory you didn't allocate.

Comment: @Yuchen Depends on the endianness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time round your second loop `i` goes up by one *and* `queue.size()` goes down by one - so you'll stop after reading half the data.

How about `while (!queue.empty())` ?

Comment: +1 Nice spotting, but I think looping to sizeof(int) is better in case there's more than one integer in the queue. EDIT: Of course probably after checking the queue wasn't empty to begin with.

Comment: I don't see how there can be more than one given that program. `assert (queue.size() == sizeof int)` might be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: Well, I assume he wants to use the queue for more than a single integer, otherwise a single int variable is probably better storage than a queue. Either way, somewhat of a strange use case so maybe I'm overthinking it :)

Comment: I want to use the queue to store all data that I receive from a socket for later use. With arrays of chars everything worked but for ints didn't. Anyway thank for help.